# The mechanism of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I accidentally found this issue on C++, but totally had no idea how it was happened, please check the code snippet below:

```
    int main() {
        int *aptr = new int(20); //Declare an integer space with 20, and aptr points to it
        shared_ptr<int> a(aptr); //Declare a shared_ptr to points where aptr points

        stringstream ss;
        ss << a;
        const char *chstr = ss.str().c_str();  // Save the address as string

        void *address;
        sscanf(chstr, "%p", (void **)&address); // Convert string back to pointer

        a = NULL;  // Free the shared pointer   
        cout << *reinterpret_cast<int*>(address) << endl; // Output: 0, 20 has gone

        return 0;
}
```

Is there anybody could tell me why the address has been freed ?
I didn't manipulate the original integer pointer "aptr", but somehow it's space has disappeared, because of the shared_ptr ?
I'd like to know how it was happend, thank you all !

Comment: Well. You shoot in your leg and then ask "why something wrong is happened"? First: you save address of temporary string, that's really bad. Second: you assign NULL to shared_ptr, instead of calling reset.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve or really what you're asking. I think you need to better understand the difference between pointers and the things that they point to.

Comment: ....  a = NULL;  nullpointer

Comment: @DanAllen well, but there is saving of `str().c_str()`. `str()` returns temporary `string`.

Comment: @ForEveR My mistake. You're right. The modification is the destruction of the temporary.

Comment: NONONO, don't get me wrong, the only purpose I save the address via string is because I have to store that dynamic integer memory without any disturbance of any other pointer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole purpose behind `std::shared_ptr` is to take ownership of the dynamically-allocated object. Once `std::shared_ptr` takes ownership of a dynamically-allocated object, via either `std::make_shared` or by directly assigning a pointer to it, `std::shared_ptr` owns it, lock stock and barrel. Owning it means automatically `delete`ing the dynamically scoped object when the last reference to the dynamically-scoped object goes out of scope. That's what the `shared_ptr` is for, and nothing else.

```
a = NULL;
```

This used `shared_ptr`'s assignment operator to replace the `shared_ptr`-owned pointer(*). Since the original dynamically-scoped object that the `shared_ptr` owns has no other reference, the `shared_ptr` `delete`s the original pointer that was used to construct it.

The fact that you still have the original, native pointer to the `int` is irrelevant. `shared_ptr` doesn't care. The whole thing gets `delete`d.

If you don't want `shared_ptr` to `delete` whatever you `new`ed, and use a native pointer for, either don't use `shared_ptr`, or make sure one is still around as long as you still need to use a native pointer to the underlying object.

(*) This actually implicitly constructs another `shared_ptr`, and uses the regular assignment operator.

Comment: Thank you very very much, it helps me a lot, very detailed, very clear.

Comment: Another think I'd like to ask is, does this take place in Android::sp (strong pointer) too ?

Answer (score 1):

This code does not compile in g++ 4.2.1 (but as Sam mentioned, it complies with version 6):

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall main.cpp 
main.cpp:17:11: error: no viable overloaded '='
        a = NULL;  // Free the shared pointer   
        ~ ^ ~~~~
```

By the way, you should use [`shared_ptr::reset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/reset/):

> In all other cases, the shared_ptr acquires ownership of p with a use
>   count of 1, and -optionally- with del and/or alloc as deleter and
>   allocator, respectively.
>
> Additionally, a call to this function has the same side effects as if
>   shared_ptr's destructor was called before its value changed (including
>   the deletion of the managed object if this shared_ptr was unique).

---

Also check [`string::c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/). You are saving the address of a temporary string, which is the start of something bad.

Comment: Compiles fine with gcc 6.3.1

Comment: Thank you @SamVarshavchik, and nice answer!